# How to implement cookie based authentication

Tags: pingfederate

I am trying to implement "Remember Me functionality" in PingFederate. For doing this I am trying t implement cookie based authentication. Before working on this I want to know any of you already worked on this and what are your thoughts ?

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First off, just to get it out of the way, I work for Ping Identity. Always good to have that up front.

Second, there may be some clarification in order, but if you're wanting to configure "remember me" functionality... Doesn't that defeat the concept of authentication? Don't you want to protect the resources that PingFed enables access to? Allowing "remember me" may be fine for something like Facebook, or WordPress, but I sure wouldn't put it in front of anything financial or health related (in fact, there are regulations against such a thing).

Finally, to actually answer your question... You'll need to create your own authentication adapter, likely built around our OpenToken SDK. The way I would handle it is to authenticate a user against whatever user repository, and create a "long-lived" cookie, one that is good for X number of days, and refreshes every time it gets used. That cookie cookie can generate an OpenToken, providing access into PF and its protected resources. You should make it so that token is a hash of something... Like a salted hash of the machine's MAC address or something similar that ties the cookie to that machine.

Again, though, I want to caution you against "remember me". It just seems like you're reducing security.

Comment: I would also add that we do offer some session based config in our HTML Form Adapter if you're using username/password based authentication.  See: http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF71R2/Configuring+the+HTML+Form+IdP+Adapter.  Lifetime can be set in terms of minutes which you could make pretty high.  In a release coming out early this year we're also enabling that cookie to be persistent to survive browser restarts.  In our latest release (7.1 R2) we also added a "Remember my username" that will at least save the user time from entering their username (nice on mobile devices).